# Django/PostGIS: How to insert coordinates in PointField in EPSG:27700, and return EPSG:4236?

Tags: postgis, geodjango, django

I am using Django 1.9 with PostGIS. I have input data that consists of British National Grid eastings and northings, and a table that looks like this:

```
class Org(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  location = models.PointField()
```

I have been setting the location of points manually as follows:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
practice.location = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s), 27700' % (lng, lat)) 
practice.save()
```

Now I want to serialize the table as GeoJSON, and I want to get WGS84 out. But the response shows the original coordinates, even though it says it is EPSG:4236:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize
results = Org.objects.filter(code__in=codes)
print HttpResponse(serialize('geojson', results,
                    geometry_field='location', 
                    fields=fields = ('name', 'location', )),
                    content_type='application/json')
```

results in GeoJSON which claims already to be in 4326:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [444139.0, 518708.0]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "THE DENSHAM SURGERY"}}]}
```

How can I change this to show the correct coordinates in EPSG:4236?

I tried the following in my serialization script:

```
for result in results:
  results.coord_property_name.wkt
  results.coord_property_name.transform(4326)
  results.coord_property_name.wkt
```

And in both cases I get the same result:

```
 POINT (366697.0000000000000000 426141.0000000000000000)
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600969/convert-between-coordinate-systems-with-geodjango) help?